# Why is a real-valued inner product defined on a Euclidean space a continuous function

Tags: linear-algebra

I really need a real maths proof that inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is an Euclidean space, is a continuous function.

Comment: Heh the original title made me laugh, imagining someone sitting there bashing their head against the wall because inner products are continuous.

Comment: Is this so obvious??? Can you explain the obvious thought of yours?

Comment: Huh?  It was a joke.  I didn't say it was obvious, the title had a something like "Inner products are continuous.  WHY?!?!" as if it was a fact about reality that made you sad.

Answer (score 4):

By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\lvert\langle x,y \rangle\rvert \leq \lVert x \rVert \cdot \lVert y \rVert$$ 
So $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a bounded bilinear form, and thus continuous.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Note that for any $x,y,\Delta x,\Delta y\in X$, we have $$\begin{align}\langle x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y\rangle &= \langle x,y+\Delta y\rangle+\langle\Delta x,y+\Delta y\rangle\\ &= \langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,\Delta y\rangle+\langle\Delta x,y\rangle+\langle\Delta x,\Delta y\rangle,\end{align}$$ so $$\begin{align}\bigl|\langle x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle\bigr| &\le \bigl|\langle x,\Delta y\rangle\bigr|+\bigl|\langle\Delta x,y\rangle\bigr|+\bigl|\langle\Delta x,\Delta y\rangle\bigr|\\ &\le \lVert x\rVert\lVert\Delta y\rVert+\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert y\Vert+\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert\Delta y\rVert.\end{align}$$ You must show that for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $x,y\in X$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $$\bigl|\langle x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle\bigr|<\epsilon$$ whenever $\lVert\Delta x\rVert,\lVert\Delta y\rVert<\delta.$

If you take this approach, you'll want to deal separately with cases that (i) $x,y=0$, (ii) one of $x,y=0$ and the other is not $0$, and (iii) $x,y\neq 0$.

---

**Added**: Case (i) is easy. Let me walk you through case (ii), and I'll leave case (iii) to you.

Suppose one of $x,y=0$ and the other is not--without loss of generality, say $x=0,y\neq0$. By the work above, we know that for any $\Delta x,\Delta y\in X$ we have $$\bigl|\langle 0+\Delta x,y+\Delta y\rangle-\langle 0,y\rangle\bigr| \le \lVert 0\rVert\lVert\Delta y\rVert+\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert y\Vert+\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert\Delta y\rVert=\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert y\Vert+\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert\Delta y\rVert.$$ Now, since $y\neq 0,$ then $\lVert y\rVert>0$, so $$\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert y\rVert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad\lVert\Delta x\rVert<\frac{\epsilon}{2\lVert y\rVert}.$$ Put $$\delta=\min\left\{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}2},\frac{\epsilon}{2\lVert y\rVert}\right\}.$$ Then $\delta>0$, and whenever $\lVert\Delta x\rVert,\lVert\Delta y\rVert<\delta,$ we have $$\begin{align}\bigl|\langle 0+\Delta x,y+\Delta y\rangle-\langle 0,y\rangle\bigr| &\le \lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert y\Vert+\lVert\Delta x\rVert\lVert\Delta y\rVert\\ &< \frac{\epsilon}{2\lVert y\rVert}\lVert y\rVert+\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}2}\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}2}\\ &= \frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2\\ &= \epsilon,\end{align}$$ as desired.

Comment: To Cameron Buie: just continue your thought but I'm afraid I missed something or did something wrong. I can't write it here because I don't know how to insert math symbols (on ipad). Is there any way I can send you an email or something with a scanned paper with my idea so you can see it?

Comment: I prefer not to distribute my e-mail address. If you aren't sure how to type out equations in LaTeX--which is the typesetting language we use, here--you can try [this online equation editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Comment: Alternately, check out [this quick guide to get you started](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you've any questions about other formatting things, feel free to ask me in a comment.

Comment: As a final alternative, do you see the link near the bottom of my answer that (currently) says "edited 1 hour ago"? If you click that then you can see exactly how I formatted my entire answer.

Comment: Check this out: http://tinypic.com/r/20tfhut/6

Comment: It looks like your first case is fine, but we can't do the same thing for the other cases (if we could, I wouldn't have told you to deal with the cases separately). Check out my edit, where I walk you through case (ii). Hopefully, that will give you an idea how to deal with case (iii), as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have an explicit formula for the inner product: $$ \langle x,y \rangle=x_1 y_1+\ldots x_n  y_n $$

This is a polynomial, therefore it is continuous (In fact it is even smooth and analytic)

Comment: Although this is more or less a correct proof, it is incomplete in the current context, because there are other inner products than the usual dot product.

Comment: This is the usual formula for the inner product, but there are another inner product formulas, like integral and some others...

Comment: This will only work for finite dimensional spaces.